# Unable to pass parameter to onclick function inside button tag

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have the following line in my code:

```
items.push("</font><button onclick='addToItinerary();' class='coolbutton' style='float: right;' id='" + results[i] + "'>add</button></ol><br> </br>");
```

I want to pass a parameter into my addToItinerary function (results[i]), but despite reading several responses to similar questions, I still can't seem to figure it out! What's going on? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this` as the parameter. The function will then receive the button element as the argument. To get `results[i]` it can access the `.id` attribute of the argument.

```
items.push("</font><button onclick='addToItinerary(this);' class='coolbutton' style='float: right;' id='" + results[i] + "'>add</button></ol><br> </br>");
```

Comment: I have function addToItinerary(button) {}, how would I access the id? I tried button.getAttribute('id') but I'm receiving [object Object] when I log it in the console, instead of a name. Any suggestions about how I can go about it?

Comment: I think that should work, but I'd just write `button.id`. I don't know why you're getting an object from this, I suspect you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: What is the value of `results[i]`? Are you sure it's a string?

Comment: You're right it was not a string! Sorry about that, my fault. But thanks for your help! I've figured it out :)